# AJAX origin null is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, basex

I am working with BASEX (an XML Database) and i am trying to connect to the http server for performing REST request using Ajax. My code work well in IE but doesn't work with Firefox or Chrome. I tried two ways for the ajax query.

Here is the first :

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "http://localhost:8984/rest/factbook?query=//city&wrap=yes", function(data)
```

This code works on IE but doesn't works on other browser, after some research I found that there is a problem with the origin:

> origin null is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin

And the second :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8984/rest/factbook?query=//city&wrap=yes",
    contentType: "xml/application",
    dataType: "xml",
```

This code works on IE and got a 404 error on other browser.

I tried to put my script on a wamp server but I got the same error :

> origin http:/localhost is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin

I also tried to replace local host by the ip of the computer but I got the same error.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: because http://localhost and http://localhost:8984 are seen as different domains. See the same origin policy.

Comment: The server serving your file must return a header called
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
with a value of * to allow all domains or specific domain name

Answer (score 2):

I guess the reason you can not get it work is that some server side coding are needed.

Try this, add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the HTTP response and set the value to *. Here's a piece of Java code for your information.

`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, some browsers do not allow CORS request to be made if the page is served from disk (null origin). This is because it is considered a security risk since all files on disk including `/home/myself/mycode.html` and `/tmp/84d8da9/dangerous_trojan.html` share the same domain: the disk. If IE allows this then it should be considered a bug. Indeed, null origin (the disk) even disallows regular non-CORS xmlHTTPrequest.

Some browsers go even further in not allowing local domains such as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `::1` to make CORS requests. So it is not enough to simply serve the page from a server.

The work-around is to give your page a domain name. For development purposes you don't have to buy a domain name. It's enough to simply modify the `hosts` file of the machine your browser is on.

---

I may have misunderstood your question. If you're not attempting a CORS request then the error is simply due to the same-origin policy (which CORS is supposed to work-around). So the solution is to simply make sure that the web page and ajax source are both served from the same domain. Regular non-CORS ajax works on local domains so make sure both your web page and the ajax source are served either from `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost:8984/`. If you want `localhost` to be able to make ajax requests to `localhost:8984` you'll have to implement CORS on the `localhost:8984` server.